# Database loadbalancing outside rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, replication, load-balancing

I want to make a master/slave setup on my postgresql servers. My problem is how I can get queries from my rails app balanced to the databases? I can't use a gem like [Octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus), because it collides with my use of the [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem (both modifies ActiveRecord) inspired by [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql). Does anyone know of a way to load balance outside the rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using [pgPool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) that allows distribution of SELECT request across a pool of servers.

Answer (score 1):

[PgBouncer](http://pgbouncer.projects.pgfoundry.org/doc/faq.html#_how_to_load_balance_queries_between_several_servers) efficiently supports both connection pooling and simple load balancing.